# Expanding $\frac{a}{a+b}$ into two terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm unsure how I arrived at this assumption but I assumed :

$$
\frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{a}{a} + \frac{a}{b}
$$

testing with values $a = 3$ and $b = 4$ this is not true as

$$
\frac{3}{3+4} \neq \frac{3}{3} + \frac{3}{4}
$$

Can $\frac{a}{a+b}$ be expanded so that $a$ exclusively is contained in its own term and $b$ is contained in its own term.

Comment: Well, if you assume false statements, you're going to run into more false statements..

Comment: For future reference, for similar problems, one hint is to think about when the expression is defined. In order for two expressions to be the same, their domains must be the same. In this case it means that the cases where the denominator is zero, have to be the same for both sides. I at least find this hint quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption, as you note, is not true at all. In particular, if you add those two fractions together and simplify a little, you get $\frac{a + b}{b}$. No such decomposition is possible.

In particular, you can never hope to express $\frac{a}{a+b}$ (or any multiple thereof as a sum of something with an $a$ in the denominator and something with a $b$ in the denominator, because $a+b$ is not a factor of $ab$ in general, but $\frac{c}{a} +\frac{d}{b} = \frac{bc+ad}{ab}$, so the denominator of it must be some factor of $ab$.